# Opera—SVG issue

Tags: svg, opera

I have got this:

```
 1| var seglist = path.pathSegList, list = [], 
 2|     x, y, ix, iy, item, nItem;
 3|
 4| for (var i = 0, n = seglist.numberOfItems; i < n; i++) {
 5|   item = seglist.getItem(i);
 6|   if (item instanceof SVGPathSegMovetoAbs) {
 7|    .
 8|   }
 9|   .
10|   .
11| }
```

and line `6` throws this error:

```
Unhandled Error: Undefined variable: SVGPathSegMovetoAbs
```

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all SVG DOM interfaces were fully exposed in Opera(Presto).

```
item instanceof SVGPathSeg
```

returns true however. If you want to check what type of segment you get, why not use the `pathSegType` or `pathSegTypeAsLetter` attributes on `SVGPathSeg` instead?